# How to get JSON data at codebehind after I've made a ajax by using xmlHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I want to transfer some json data to server by using JavaScript xmlHttpRequest. 
For simplify, assume that I've got a json like `{"name":"John","country":"English"}`, then I'm going to POST it back to the server. I use `Request["name"]` to get the request data but always result in NullOrEmpty, which means I cannot get inside **#1**. Thus leading to that **#2** shows the entire HTML Document.

Here's my code:

```
**JavaScript:**
    function AjaxTest()
    {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                alert(xhttp.responseText);//**#2.**
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "WebForm.aspx", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

        var json = '{"name":"John","country":"English"}';
        xhttp.send(json);
    }

**Codebehind:**
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string name = Request["name"];
            string country = Request["country"];
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(country))
            {
                //**#1.** I cannot get here.
            }
        }
    }
```

I do know that I've done something wrong, but how can I get the reques data? As a newbie to Ajax, any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser dev tools in order to see if the request is sent correctly.

Comment: do you have any idea about [WebMethod] attribute?

Comment: From where does your method takes request object?

Comment: @yuriy636 The async request do has a respond as I found that instructions in `onreadystatechange` event handler had been exectued.

Comment: @MMK [WebMethod] makes the method to be static so that it is not convenient to reference server controls.

Comment: @Sohil I'm sorry, I don't know what you exactly refer to. It's a property of the requested `System.Web.UI.Page` if you mean the Request object in `Page_Load` method. Otherwise, please forgive my bad ASP.NET knowledge.